# Sending arguments through a CodeLens request in an LSP extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, plugins, vscode-extensions

I'm currently working on an extension using the LSP provided by Microsoft and have run into the following problem.

I have created an array of CodeLenses using the `connection.OnCodeLens()` function, which are filled with objects like the following:

```js
codeLenses.push({
    range: {
       start: { line: i, character: 0 },
       end: { line: i, character: 8 }
     },
     command,
     data: 0,
     arguments: i
});
```

Also, here is how the command is created in the package.json file

```
{
    "command": "extensionName.commandName",
     "title": "Run Test",
     "category": "CodeLens Sample",
     "arguments": []
}
```

The command is created before pushing to the `codeLenses` array and has the title of 'Run Test'. When I press 'Run Test' on the client extension, the function `connection.onExecuteCommand(handler)` is called, but the handler does not have any arguments attached to it (i.e. it has an array of length 0).

I want to know the line where the 'Run Test' command was clicked. How can I send arguments through the codeLens so that I can read them on the `executeCommand` function?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but it might be useful to someone.

You pass the `arguments` in the wrong place. You need to pass them as a property in the command object not in the code lens itself.

The command passed in the code lens now should look like this

```
{
    "command": "extensionName.commandName",
     "title": "Run Test",
     "category": "CodeLens Sample",
     "arguments": [1]
}
```